# Why noscript and skel are not working in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, noscript

I'm using Miniport Template.
 A demo can be found [here](http://templatecreme.com/list/miniport-template/).

The head section looks like as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Miniport 2.5 by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @n33co
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Miniport by HTML5 UP</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600,700"       rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/config.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
```

There is nothing changed but added `<?php wp_head(); ?>` when converting it into wordpress theme.
But css is broken, It looks like the page is not getting the css when `<noscript>` is there.
Also responsiveness is broken when converting the original theme into wordpress.
How to fix 1.noscript issue 2. responsiveness issue ?

Answer (score 0):

you're calling stylesshets in a wrong way. change the css calls to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/skel-noscript.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/style-desktop.css" />
```

But I recommend you to create a style.css in your index folder, then use @import to other sheets. for this, change the calling to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
```

Notice: do the same with js files.

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/config.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/skel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the script i showed is just the html one. By the way best practice of calling stylesheet and js is using wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script in functions.php.